# Developer error Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, gmail

Al querer loguearse con gmail Firebase en la app sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que he leido uno de los fallos es debido a que el firmado la apk con otra key SHA-1 distinta a la que tengo en firebase pero al intentar añadir la nueva en Firebase se me queda un rato pensando y luego no aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna forma de poder arreglar el error?

Comment: Lujan, ¿esta aplicación esta en Google Play o únicamente la subiste desde Android Studio?

Comment: Está en la playstore en prueba interna para unos pocos

Comment: entonces el SHA-1 debe ser de el keystore con el que firmaste el .apk, ¿esto es así? @lujan

Comment: por lo que he leido creo que si, lo que no se hacer es meter la nueva SHA-1 en firebase

Comment: selecciona el tipo SHA-1 y agregala @lujan

Comment: le doy a añadir huella digital, pego la que me sale en signinReport se queda unos 30 segundos procesando y cuando termina no aparece ningún tipo de aviso

Comment: podrias imprimir el stacktrace de ese error y pegar el logcat ? muchas gracias

Comment: acordate que el sha-1 debe ser el de produccion y no el de debug si ya tenes la app en el store

Answer (score 0):

Este error esta relacionado como comentabamos arriba con la firma de tu app , existen dos tipos de SHA1 , el de debug y el de release, el de debug lo podes encontrar de la siguiente forma

te vas a la solapa de la parte arriba a la derecha y clickas `gradle - tu proyecto - tasks - signingReport`

Luego abajo te aparecera tu SHA1 (este es el de debug , imagen derecha)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, en tu build.gradle te dice el paquete con el que deberias firmar en la [Consola de Firebase](http://console.firebase.google.com).

Para obtener el SHA1 de produccion o Release, abris la terminal en el android studio y haces lo siguiente, te posicionas en la carpeta bin que viene con el SDK , generalmente la encuentras en la carpeta `javac` (usualmente en `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin` ) . Luego escribes lo siguiente

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

por ejemplo

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Usuario\tu_usuario\Desktop\prueba.jks -alias prueba
```

El SHA1 de produccion deberia ser el que usarias cuando tu app este en el PlayStore

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y perdón por no contestar antes, al seguir tus pasos me da un error al final: -error de herramienta de claves: java.lang.Exception: El archivo de almacén de claves no existe:
Como la app la tengo para testear con los amigos es posible que cuando la tenga finalizada la pueda subir otra vez con la SHA1 que me marca Firebase y asi que me funcione sin tener este fallo????, al subir otra vez me refiero a subirla desde cero y borrar la que tengo en la playstore